# How to change the slug in the url based on the language selected using gatsby-theme-i18n-react-i18next?

Tags: localization, gatsby, react-i18next

I have a project that uses Gatsby and for localization, I have used [gatsby-plugin-react-i18next](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/) plugin. How can I change the slug in the URL based on the language selected. For example, I have a page named product.js under the pages folder. In French language, I want the page as https://www.example.com/fr/produit instead of https://www.example.com/product.

Answer (score 0):

You have a [bunch of options](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/#plugin-api) available using the `gatsby-plugin-react-i18next` plugin. In your case, `language` holds the currently selected language.

You have (at least) two options:

- Using the exposed Link component from `gatsby-plugin-react-i18next`:

  ```
  import {Link} from 'gatsby-plugin-react-i18next';

  const SpanishAboutLink = () => {

     const {language} = useI18next();

    <Link to="/about" language={language}>
       About page in Spanish
     </Link>
  };
  ```

  The plugin wraps the `Link` component from Gatsby adding a custom prop (`language`) that can be filled with the exposed state of `useI18next` hook.
- Using the built-in `Link` (from Gatsby) and using a template literal:

  ```
  const SpanishAboutLink = () => {

     const {language} = useI18next();

    <Link to=`{language}/about`>
       About page in the selected language
     </Link>
  };
  ```

  In this approach, you are getting the current language in the same way as before but you are concatenating it to a `Link` component to create a URL based on that parameter.

In your case, since you are changing the slug in both pages (*product* and *produit*), you'll need to query both using a page query and applying one of the previous approaches dynamically. For example:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

 const HomePage = ({data}) => {
      const {language} = useI18next();
 return (
    <div>
     <Link to={`${language}/${data.allYourPagesQuery.edges.node[0].slug}`}>
      {data.allYourPagesQuery.edges.node[0].title}
     </Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query HomePageQuery {
    allYourPagesQuery{
      edges {
        node {
         name
         slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default HomePage
```

Due to the lack of details in your implementation and your data sources, I'm not able to guess how your query should look like. But assuming you have a way of retrieving the `title` and the `slug` of your available pages you can do something like the snippet above.

Comment: Do I have to create the file produit.js under pages separately for french?

Comment: Ideally, yes. It can be achieved tweaking how Gatsby create pages by adding some plugins (i18, etc).